# PHP Retaining personal session info when checking other profiles

Tags: php, pdo

I have a social site I'm developing, in which the database stores unique id's for each user. I have managed to update the profile page to show the users details based on the id. However, I need to retain the information for the logged in user as well and have come to a roadblock. On the site there is a dropdown for the specific user that's logged in (Name with logout button), but it currently changes to the data of the other user's id instead of being the logged in users data. Here is the code so far:

On the profile page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.channel.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
$user_home->redirect('login.php');
}

/* Get unique ID */
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$_SESSION['userSession'] = $_GET['id']; 
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


?>
```

And where the logged-in users' dropdown is called:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user"></i> 
        <?php echo $row['userName']; ?> <i class="caret"></i>
                                </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a tabindex="-1" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I feel like I may be going about this backward. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your entire site wrapped in a loop? You should use a session variable for the logged in users, not fetch from the database every time a page is loaded. Only set the logged in users data when the user logs in, using [PHP Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) or something similar like cookies

Comment: not quite sure what your doing but ... `$_SESSION['userSession'] = $_GET['id'];` this doesn't seem right, basically I could go to your site and make myself any user based on setting a GET variable id to any number

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the ID of the user logged in inside the session. Instead, you are getting it from the `$_GET` parameter.

This is the problem code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$_SESSION['userSession'] = $_GET['id']; 
}
```

The `$_SESSION['userSession']` should only be set once when the user logs into your application.

The `$_GET['id']` is the ID of the user you are currently viewing. Not the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
<?php
if( session_id() = '' )
{
    @session_start();
}

//include the class 
require_once 'class.channel.php';
    
    $user_home = new USER();

    if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
    {
        // Redirect user if not already loggedIn
        $user_home->redirect('login.php');
    }
    else{
        /* Get unique ID 
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            $_SESSION['userSession'] = $_GET['id']; 
        }
        */
        
        $userID = ( isset( $_GET['id']) && !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ) ? trim($_GET['id']) : '' ;
    }

    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$userID );
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if( count( $row ) > 0 )
    {
        // You can set session here if not already set when logged in
        if( $_SESSION['userSession'] == '' )
        {
            $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['userID']; //  use id from database to store in the session to prevent hacking 
        }
    }


?>
```

**Let's know how it's going**

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented these changes. However, on the other profiles the menu dropdown still renders the other person's profile data. Should I change <?php echo $row['userName']; ?> based on this?

Comment: I changed it to <?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?> (defined in class.channel.php) and it appears to be working. Or should I go about it another way?

Comment: @Cordell Since I don't see your class.channel.php I only re-coded this part  based on code that you've shown to us.  If it's working, great!  Glad to be of help, if there's anything else, do not hesitate to ask.  Happy Coding :)